# Flagged a question about sharing Wifi - flag was declined

Tags: discussion

I flagged 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478890/sharing-wifi-with-neighbor) this to be moved, but it was declined - "no evidence to support it".  It was then put on hold.

Question - why was the flag declined when the question was way off topic and could be moved to the right group?

Comment: What kind of flag did you use? Keep in mind that we don't migrate crap which might be the reason the moderator declined your flag for that particular question.

Comment: I used the 'other' choice when flagging, and asked for it to be moved.  So questions that are off-topic and crap should just be closed?  The problem is that I may know something is off-topic but not that it is crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have choosen the Other flag. Use other only if a moderator is needed to handle the situation. Always prefer to have the community handle quality issues.

You can flag a question for closing. This example question could be flagged as off-topic -> better suited for Super User.

After you flagged the question is sent to the close vote queue where 5 users with 3K repuatation will close vote the question.

No moderator will be hurt in the process.

Migration of questions is possible but only adviced if the question it self is of enough quality to stay open on the target site. Questions that need editing/formatting and are unclear are better left on the orginal site and closed or improved. Rejected migrations are not beneficial to anyone.

Comment: True, that is just a wall of text in there. Might be salvageable, but guess it's not worth the time.